# Помогите, какая то проблема с отображением фотошопа в Панели задач

Tags: windows-10, icon, photoshop

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
Понимаю не совсем вопрос уместен здесь но надеюсь кто то поможет решить проблему
 Photoshop CC 2019
```

Comment: открепите да закрепите заново, если закреплен был.

Answer (score 0):

Запустите командную строку от имени администратора и поочередно выполните все эти команды.

```
taskkill /im explorer.exe /f
assoc.exe=exefile
assoc.lnk=lnkfile
cd %userprofile%\appdata\local
attrib -h IconCache.db
del IconCache.db
explorer
```

После этого перезагрузитесь.